# dynamically load UICollectionView in xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios4

We have a label followed by a UIViewCollection. The height of the label is dynamically set based on its content. Based on the height of the label, we want to start the UIViewCollection as soon as the label ends. We are tracking the label x, y, width and height and adding some padding to y in the code to calculate the start of UIViewCollection. However, UIViewCollection does not move at all. Is it because of the specified storyboard? We tried it in ViewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear.

Also, if we replace the UIViewCollection with a label such that there are 2 labels one below another, we are able to dynamically load the start of the 2nd label if the code is placed in ViewWillAppear.

Please can someone help with moving the UIViewCollection up or down based on the previous label height?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because You use autolayout. You can switch off autolayout or set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints YES for UIViewCollection, and than set current location

Answer (score 0):

If you're using auto layout this is easy to do, and you don't need to do anything in code to keep track of the label's height. The label should have a height constraint to the top of the view and a spacing constraint to the top of the collection view (the length of that constraint will give you whatever padding you want between them). The collection view then needs a constraint to the bottom of the view. This setup will cause the collection view to get shorter when the label gets taller. If instead, you want the height of the collection view to stay the same, but move down (assuming that it's short enough that there's room to move down), give the collection view a fixed height constraint, and remove its constraint to the bottom of the view.